# Two uiwebview but only one works

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to implement 2 Web views using the storyboard, both linked to another online webpage.
For some reason I don't get any errors, but only the PricesViewController works.
The other VC generates a white page......

I am using these 4 files:

PricesViewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface PricesViewController : UIViewController

 {
     IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView; }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *WebView;

 @end
```

PricesViewController.m

```
 #import "PricesViewController.h"

 @interface PricesViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation PricesViewController @synthesize WebView;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sparein.be/full_pricelist.pdf"]]];
      [super viewDidLoad];

 }


 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
     }
     return self; }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

 @end
```

ReservationsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ReservationsViewController : UIViewController

 {
     IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView2; }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *WebView2;

 @end
```

ReservationsViewController.m

```
#import "ReservationsViewController.h"

 @interface ReservationsViewController ()
   @end

 @implementation ReservationsViewController @synthesize WebView2;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [WebView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.be"]]];

     [super viewDidLoad];
     }


 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
     }
     return self; }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }

 @end
```

Comment: Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` methods, maybe they can tell you something about what's happening.

Comment: make sure you've not forgetting to give reference to WebView2 from .xib file of ReservationsViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not fix your problem, but try this. Change your `PricesViewController.h` and `ReservationsViewController.h` similarly. Also, what version of Xcode are you using, and what version of iOS are you targeting? You shouldn't need `@synthesize` in your .m if you're using a recent version of Xcode and iOS.

```
@interface PricesViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;

@end
```

`IBOutlet`s should not be retained, as this can cause retain cycles. May not be the cause, but good programming practice anyway.

Comment: Xcode version 4.6.3, targetting iOS 6.1.
Removing @synthesize WebView; causes an error at WebViewloadRequest

Comment: Double-check that your `UIWebView` outlet in your .xib file is connected to the .h file `IBOutlet`.

Comment: Solved! The referencing outlet wasn't connected. Stupid mistake :-). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Click the accept button on my answer if you would. That marks it as the accepted answer. Thanks!